# I want to understand this "duplicates?" method

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I can't seem to wrap my head around this method. If I would try to comprehend this code I would say that the items are iterated over and indexed twice so that there are two seperate iterations of the array. If both collections of indexes are the same return true if both collections of items are the same.

```
def duplicates?(array1)
  array1.each_with_index do |item1, index1|
    array1.each_with_index do |item2, index2|
      next if index1 == index2
      return true if item1 == item2
    end
  end
  false
end
```

Obviously i'm mistaken otherwise the method would always return true. How am i mistaken?

Comment: Without any idea about ruby, i think the idea is the following: for each element, check each other if there is an equality. If there is one: return True; meaning there is a duplicate (stop algorithm; it's just binary check, recognizable by the ? in the function-name). Else: continue. If all checks passed, return false = no dupes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm is

```
for each element in array
  for each element in array
    skip if indices match
    return true if elements are the same 

return false
```

Pretty simple really.

Comment: Ahh so next if index == index2 will skip the matching elements if their indices match and it will return true if one of the items in the array match. It makes perfect sense now. Thank you.